# creating database and inserting values from text file using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been  trying to split the content of my text file. I want to create a database table out of the text and also insert the values of the text into the created database.The database creation is successful but inserting the values does not work. Only one(1) row of the value is inserted.

eligibilitycheck.txt

> ,@ID::@ID/EM.PRDL.ELIGIBILITY.ID::EM.PRDL.ELIGIBILITY.ID/PRODUCT.ID::PRODUCT.ID/MIN.AGE::MIN.AGE/MIN.AGE.BRK::MIN.AGE.BRK/MAX.AGE::MAX.AGE/MAX.AGE.BRK::MAX.AGE.BRK/GENDER::GENDER/GENDER.BRK::GENDER.BRK/RESIDENCE::RESIDENCE/RESIDENCE.BRK::RESIDENCE.BRK/NATIONALITY::NATIONALITY/NATIONALITY.BRK::NATIONALITY.BRK/CLASSIFICATION::CLASSIFICATION/CLASSIFICATION.BRK::CLASSIFICATION.BRK/PROFESSION::PROFESSION/PROFESSION.BRK::PROFESSION.BRK/INIT.DEP.CCY::INIT.DEP.CCY/INIT.DEP.PERC::INIT.DEP.PERC/INIT.DEP.AMT::INIT.DEP.AMT/INIT.DEP.OTH.CCY::INIT.DEP.OTH.CCY/INIT.DEP.BRK::INIT.DEP.BRK/PARTIAL.BLOCKING::PARTIAL.BLOCKING/MIN.CUS.MONTHS::MIN.CUS.MONTHS/MIN.CUS.BRK::MIN.CUS.BRK/MIN.SAV.MONTHS::MIN.SAV.MONTHS/MIN.SAV.BRK::MIN.SAV.BRK/LOAN.PURPOSE::LOAN.PURPOSE/LOAN.PURPOSE.BRK::LOAN.PURPOSE.BRK/SOURCE.FUNDS::SOURCE.FUNDS/SOURCE.FUNDS.BRK::SOURCE.FUNDS.BRK/STATUS::STATUS/DATE.TIME::DATE.TIME,"Advanced
>   " "Advanced                                          "    "Advanced
>   " "  "    "                                   "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "NG       " "ERROR                              "   "         " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1801040550","AgricLoans
>   " "AgricLoans                                        "    "AgricLoans
>   " "18"    "ERROR                              "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "         " "                                   "   "         " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1712030832","BOINPF
>   " "BOINPF                                            "    "BOINPF
>   " "  "    "                                   "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "NG       " "ERROR                              "   "         " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1801020906","ConsumerLoansRecruit
>   " "ConsumerLoansRecruit
>   " "ConsumerLoansRecruit"  "18"    "ERROR                              "   " 
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "NG       " "ERROR
>   " "         " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "NGN"   "     " "                  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "CREATED                            "   "     1801040636","Corporate
>   " "Corporate                                         "    "Corporate
>   " "  "    "                                   "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "         " "                                   "   "NG       " "ERROR
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   " 20"   "ERROR
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1801072319","DirectorsShareLoan
>   " "DirectorsShareLoan
>   " "DirectorsShareLoan  "  "  "    "                                   "   " 
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "NG       " "ERROR
>   " "         " "                                   "   "8
>   " "ERROR                              "   "    "  "
>   " "NGN"   "     " "                  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "CREATED                            "   "     1801040718","INSTITUTION
>   " "INSTITUTION                                       "    "INSTITUTION
>   " "  "    "                                   "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "NG       " "ERROR                              "   "         " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1801100649","MICROLOANS
>   " "MICROLOANS                                        "    "MICROLOANS
>   " "18"    "ERROR                              "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "         " "                                   "   "         " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1712030542","NewSpecial
>   " "NewSpecial                                        "    "NewSpecial
>   " "  "    "                                   "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "         " "                                   "   "         " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   100000"   "NO                                 "   "ERROR
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1801180830","PINKLADIES
>   " "PINKLADIES                                        "    "PINKLADIES
>   " "  "    "                                   "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "NG       " "OVERRIDE                           "   "         " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1712050109","POWA
>   " "POWA                                              "    "POWA
>   " "  "    "                                   "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "NG       " "OVERRIDE                           "   "         " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1801100618","SMARTIESSHARED
>   " "SMARTIESSHARED                                    "    "SMARTIESSHARED
>   " "  "    "                                   "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "NG       " "ERROR                              "   "         " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1712180555","SpecialShared
>   " "SpecialShared                                     "    "SpecialShared 
>   " "18"    "OVERRIDE                           "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "         " "                                   "   "         " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1712170047","TermLoan
>   " "TermLoan                                          "    "TermLoan
>   " "18"    "ERROR                              "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "         " "                                   "   "         " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1712170133","WEWE1
>   " "WEWE1                                             "    "WEWE1
>   " "  "    "                                   "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "NG       " "ERROR                              "   "         " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1801020548","WeWeNPF
>   " "WeWeNPF                                           "    "WeWeNPF
>   " "  "    "                                   "   "  "    "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "         " "                                   "   "         " "
>   " "8                                  "   "ERROR
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "NGN"   "     " "
>   " "                                   "   "
>   " "                                   "   "    "  "
>   " "    "  "                                   "   "   "   "
>   " "   "   "                                   "   "CREATED
>   " "     1801040753"

function

```
global $tablename,$dbc;

function create_insert ($tablename){
global$response,$tablename,$dbc;


$response=file_get_contents("eligibilitycheck.txt");



$myspliter=explode(',',$response);
 global $logo,$valuedata,$crmd,$keys1;
 global $dbc,$CRMDATA,$value,$fielddata,$tablefields1,$tablefieldsforinsert;
  $counts=count($myspliter);

  $header1=explode('/',$myspliter[1]);
   $headers=explode('/',$header1[1]);


 foreach($header1 as $header ){
    $newheader=explode(':',$header);
    if (strpos(':',$header) == false) {
        $newheader=explode(':',$header);
        //print_r($newheader);
        //echo ("<td><b>$newheader[0]</b></td>");   

        $fielddata .= "`$newheader[0]`,";
        //$fielddata .= str_replace('.','_',"`$newheader[0]`,");

    //$fields=$newheader[0];
    $fields=str_replace('.','_',$newheader[0]);
    $keys1="`$fields` VARCHAR(225),";
    $tablefields1 .=$keys1;
    //$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `crmtest`($keys1)";


    $keysforinsert="`$fields`,";
    $tablefieldsforinsert .=$keysforinsert;


}
    else{

    // echo ("<td><b><$newheader[1]</b></td>");
     $fielddata .= "`$newheader[1]`";
     //$fielddata .= str_replace('.','_',"`$newheader[1]`,");
     //$replace1=str_replace('_','.',$key);
     //$fields=$newheader[0];
    $fields=str_replace('.','_',$newheader[0]);
    $keys1="`$fields` VARCHAR(225),";
    $tablefields1 .=$keys1;


    $keysforinsert="`$fields`,";
    $tablefieldsforinsert .=$keysforinsert;


    }
 }
 //$tablefields = implode(',', $keys1);
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$tablename`($tablefields1`status1` VARCHAR(225),`transactionmode` VARCHAR(225))";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

$q = mysqli_query($dbc,"ALTER TABLE `$tablename` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`@ID`)");
//echo "</tr></thead><tbody><tr>";


//echo "<br>$tablefields1 <br><p>";




    //table fields successfully derieved
//echo "<br>$tablefieldsforinsert <br><p>";

//end of creating table part of the function

for($i = 2; $i<count($myspliter);$i++){
       $row =$myspliter[$i];

       //echo "$row";

      $cells =explode('"',$row);

    //print_r( $cells);

    foreach($cells as $newcells){

    $newvalue=explode('"',$newcells);

    //print_r( $newvalue);
        //echo "$newvalue";
    }



      //$cellscrm =array_filter(explode('"',$row));

      $source_array=array_filter(explode('"',$row));
      //array_map('trim', $source_array);
       // print_r($source_array);

      $cellscrm =array_map('trim', $source_array);
      if($cellscrm[1]==""){
          continue;
      }

      $newfieddata=str_replace('.','_',$fielddata);

      //print_r($newfieddata);

      //echo "$cellscrm";

      foreach($cells as $key=>$value){

  //$final=array_filter(array_map('trim', $value));
                if($key % 2==0){
                 continue;
                 }

        $valuedata .= "'$value',";


             //$newfields.="$tablefieldsforinsert";

        //echo "INSERT INTO `SNAPPELIGIBILITYCHECK`($tablefieldsforinsert`status1`) VALUES($valuedata'') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status` ='Active',`transactionmode`='Online' <br>";

      }

      //echo "$valuedata <br>";

      //print_r($cells);

      $query_values = implode(',',$cells);

        //echo "$query_values<br>"; 

      //    echo "INSERT INTO `SNAPPELIGIBILITYCHECK`($tablefieldsforinsert`status1`) VALUES($valuedata'') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status` ='Active',`transactionmode`='Online' <br>";

  $CRMDATA =mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO `$tablename`($tablefieldsforinsert`status1`) VALUES($valuedata'') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status` ='Active',`transactionmode`='Online'");
             echo "<br>";


    //  echo "</tr>"; 




  }//end of for loop



}// end of account statement functions





 $tablename="newtable";

 create_insert ($tablename);
```

Comment: are there no line feeds in that text file?

Comment: I assume from your debugging, you saw the insert query ```$CRMDATA =mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO `$tablename`($tablefieldsforinsert`status1`) VALUES($valuedata'') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status` ='Active',`transactionmode`='Online'");``` being repeated?  Is this exactly the way the query is constructed?  With all the back tics and single quotes in there I'm amazed it isn't throwing a syntax error.

Comment: @TimMorton there are no line feeds, but  there is a common delimiter (,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this codes.
Your table creation is ok, I see all the fields populated. you needed to create an array of your $value and push the values to it before inserting into the database.

```
    for($i = 2; $i<count($myspliter);$i++){
       $row =$myspliter[$i];

       //echo "$row";

      $cells =explode('"',$row);


    //print_r( $cells);

    foreach($cells as $newcells){

    $newvalue=explode('"',$newcells);

    //print_r( $newvalue);
        //echo "$newvalue";
    }
    //$cellscrm =array_filter(explode('"',$row));

      $source_array=array_filter(explode('"',$row));
      //array_map('trim', $source_array);
       // print_r($source_array);

      $cellscrm =array_map('trim', $source_array);
      if($cellscrm[1]==""){
          continue;
      }

      $newfieddata=str_replace('.','_',$fielddata);


      $values = array();

      foreach($cells as $key=>$value){

  //$final=array_filter(array_map('trim', $value));
                if($key % 2==0){
                 continue;
                 }

                   $values[] = "'$value'"; 
                //$values1=implode(' ',$cells[1]);

      }

      $query_values = implode(',',$values);


    //echo "$query_values<br>"; 

//echo "INSERT INTO `SNAPPELIGIBILITYCHECK`($tablefieldsforinsert`status1`) VALUES($query_values,'') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status` ='Active',`transactionmode`='Online' <br>";

 $CRMDATA =mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO `$tablename`($tablefieldsforinsert`status1`) VALUES($query_values,'') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status` ='Active',`transactionmode`='Online'");
             echo "<br>";


    //  echo "</tr>"; 




  }//end of for loop
```